# Which 4xx http status code for REST

Tags: java, spring, rest, http, http-status-codes

We have a RESTful architecture and I have a question regarding to exceptions and http statuses for our API.

We use `400` for cases:

- value mismatch (for instance, expected 100 but was 99)
- violations of @Size, @Min, @Max, @Nullable anc etc

Use `422` (unprocessable entity) for cases when something wrong with logic, but it is not a client mistake. For example, trying to set category to product which already has one. This is unpredictable on the client side.

Finally, we use `409` (conflict) for cases when it is a client's error.
For example, if he is trying to send invalid `Date` format via `JSON`. Or registration date is far away before current.

But one case fits into a few categories:
We have a `Tax` field which is integral number.

If client sends *fractional* `Tax` then exception should be thrown.

From one side, this is clearly `400` and client should see 'Tax cannot be fractional'.

But, from other side - it is a client's programmer error, since he is trying to send ***Double/Float*** instead of ***Integer/Long*** (i.e. he sends *another* type, it's like pass *Long* instead of *String*) and 409 should be thrown.

What should I choose: `400` or `409` for `TypeMismatch` in `Numbers` case?
And if `400`, why should I make an exusement for Number types but throw `409` for `Date/String` cases of `TypeMismatch`?

I would prefer answers with a definite logic rather then a "I think". This is not a discussion.

Comment: I smell an opinion based question, so no matter what you choose to do, just be consistent.

Comment: my opinion on this would be to stick to standards-based definitions for the use of http responses.

Comment: Dear Close-Voters: This question is not opinion based. The HTTP Responses are sufficiently well described to produce a definite answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I concur with the opinion-based question comment, but I'll also throw this out there:

[image]

Comment: Right-click, view image and you should get the raw file.  Alternatively, it's here: http://i.stack.imgur.com/whhD1.png

Comment: Is this file your own production or is it "the standard" of some sorts? If the latter, where did you get it from?

Comment: It's not mine - I saw it maybe 2 or 3 years ago, and just googled for it just now.

Comment: This picture doesn't provide answer what should be thrown if passed entity is valid (passes validation in very beginning), but has some contradiction with server state. But this contradiction is not so strong to throw Internal Server Error 500 (it is heavy weapon indicating that server is in non-consistance state).

Comment: @user2138356 If I apply that image I end up at '409' -> You PUT in the update and it conflicts the server state. Or if it is the update in the end that fails (unpredicted by your handling) then its '500' for 'something unexpected went wrong'.

Comment: Alternative graph: http://clojure-liberator.github.io/liberator/assets/img/decision-graph.svg Same result and as far as I can see same content as well.

Comment: For people like me who want to know who made the digram in this answer: As far as I could find it is of [@andrei-neculau](http://stackoverflow.com/users/465684/andrei-neculau) who has a newer version of this on this github project: https://github.com/for-GET/http-decision-diagram

Answer (score 0):

Opinion: Since types are more fundamental I would throw a 409

Comment: Yes, I stand with the same point of view. It is more `programmer` way to think.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you would a `409` for any of these cases.
Here is what Wikipedia says about `409`:

> Indicates that the request could not be processed because of conflict
>   in the request, such as an edit conflict in the case of multiple
>   updates.

I would use `400` for the number types as well as the `Date/String` case.

But it is a matter of personal flavor, both status codes are possible as long as you stay consistent throughout your API.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly I would prefer status code `400` or `422` for your use case since the provided entity can't be processed because of its content. This can be something structural (wrong types, missing required fields, ...) or data validation (wrong format using regexp, not allowed values, duplicate values, ...).

Status code `409` should be rather used for optimistic locking, as described in the link http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html:

> 10.4.10 409 Conflict
>
> The request could not be completed due to a conflict with the current state of the resource. This code is only allowed in situations where it is expected that the user might be able to resolve the conflict and resubmit the request. The response body SHOULD include enough information for the user to recognize the source of the conflict. Ideally, the response entity would include enough information for the user or user agent to fix the problem; however, that might not be possible and is not required.
>
> Conflicts are most likely to occur in response to a PUT request. For example, if versioning were being used and the entity being PUT included changes to a resource which conflict with those made by an earlier (third-party) request, the server might use the 409 response to indicate that it can't complete the request. In this case, the response entity would likely contain a list of the differences between the two versions in a format defined by the response Content-Type.

Hope it helps you,
Thierry